# XPath string as input

Tags: python, xml, xpath, flask, lxml

Considering the code example below,

```
if 'xpath' in request.args:
    in = request.args['xpath']
    xml = BytesIO(open("/file.xml").read())
    for v, e in etree.iterparse(xml):
         return e.text
```

the following XML file,

```
<a>
   <c>
      <d>content X</d>
   </c>
   <c>
      <d>content Y</d>
   </c>
</a>
```

and that the `in` variable receives the string `/a/c[2]/d` with curl, as bellow

```
curl http://localhost:5000/home?xpath=/a/c[2]/d
```

is there any way that from the given string (xpath expression) the code returns the element text (i.e. is able to understand which element I'm referring to)?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for. What do you expect as output? XPath is exactly design to refer to an element within XML, thats the whole purpose of the language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the element located by `in`, you can call the `find` method on the parsed `ElementTree`.

```
return etree.parse(xml).find(in).text
```

Note that the XPath expression must not include the root element itself, nor a starting slash, so `c[2]/d` should do the trick.

Comment: You mean that I have to parse the xml file to make something like described [here](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#generating-xpath-expressions)? @Valéry

Comment: Why should the XPath expression not include the root element? @Valéry

Comment: It returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
But I want to use the expression from the root like /a/c/d
Any way for this to work like that?

Comment: `find` works relative to the root element, so it does not see it. You can remove the beginning of the expression up to the second `/` (or maybe prepend `..`).

Comment: Ok. But what if I still want to use the entire path? (i.e. /a/c/d) Because that's what I type in the URL (e.g. http://ip:5000/link?xpath=/a/c/d) @Valéry

Comment: Then have your GET handler remove `/a/` before calling `find`.

Comment: you mean like doing `in = request.args['xpath'].split("/")` and then `pop(0)` the first element (/a) ?

Comment: Yes, and join back with `'/'` without the root.

Comment: But isn't this method a bit unprofessional? What if I want to make sure that the root tag is indeed the `a`? I could just type in the URL `http://ip:5000/link?xpath=/z/c/d` and the `z` node does not exist. Isn't there anything other that find() to accept the entire xpath expression?

Comment: Also, I don't want to have to do something like `if in[0] is not 'a'` to make sure that the root node name is `a` because imagine that for some reason I change the XML file. The code will become deprecated